# Spark UI Output Op Duration vs Job Duration: What's the difference?

Tags: spark-streaming

On Spark UI page, what is the difference of column: "Output Op Duration" and "Job Duration"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Sparks [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg61442.html):

"It means the total time to run a batch, including the Spark job duration +
time spent on the driver. E.g.,

```
foreachRDD { rdd =>
   rdd.count() // say this takes 1 second.
   Thread.sleep(10000) // sleep 10 seconds
}
```

In the above example, the Spark job duration is 1 seconds and the output op
duration is 11 seconds."